# How to properly close and unlink shared memory of multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, pool

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing module and to add 1 to the shared memory in each process. But, I see the errors when running the following code.
Can anyone tell how to close and unlink the shared momery?

Here is the code.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, shared_memory

def counter():
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name = 'shm')
    c = existing_shm.buf
    old_state = c[0]
    c[0] = old_state + 1
    print(c[0])
    existing_shm.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Pool(12)
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create = True, size = 1, name= 'shm')
    buffer = shm.buf
    buffer[0] = 0

    for i in range(20):
        #p.apply(counter, args = (state, ))
        p.apply(counter)

    p.close()
    p.join()

    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
```

The error messages are follows.

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/multiprocess_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    p.apply(counter)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 357, in apply
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/shm'
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:224: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:237: UserWarning: resource_tracker: '/shm': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/shm'
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: %r: %s' % (name, e))
```

Comment: my environment is follows.

python 3.10
wsl ubuntu

Comment: Do you _only_ intend to run inside WSL? If you don't need native Windows compatibility you can rely on multiprocessing's forking mode to not need to separately open the SHM segment from inside the subprocesses (inheriting the handle from the parent process instead).

Comment: BTW, you can safely call `shm.unlink()` _before_ all handles are closed; it doesn't immediately deallocate the memory, but rather marks it for deallocation after all the processes that have it opened have exited (and prevents processes from opening it by name going forward, but newly created processes can still inherit old handles by forking). Same as the semantics around files on UNIX (where it's common practice to unlink temporary files very early -- _especially_ ones that are being memory-mapped for shm-style semantics).

Comment: As an aside: You are calling `pool.apply`, which blocks until the submitted task completes and your worker function `counter` returns some value (`None` in your case). You are *not* running anything in parallel if you do this and there is no point in using multiprocessing. Perhaps you meant to use method `apply_async`.

Comment: Also, if you do use `apply_async`, then you will have multiple processes attempting to increment you shared memory in parallel. But this operation is not atomic because you must fetch a value from shared memory, increment that value and finally store the new, updated value. This is 3 operations and two or more tasks might be fetching the same value. You need to do this incrementing under control of a multiprocessing lock.

Comment: "Do you only intend to run inside WSL?"  Actually, no. But I want to know how to deallocate the memory in a proper way. Thanks for your information about forking mode.

Comment: I modify the code. but the error message is the same...

Comment: "Actually, no." Make sure to test in both then.. IIRC on Windows, the file is deleted after all instances are `close`d, and `unlink` is actually a noop. On posix, `unlink` is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue with Windows WSL2 (debian) and I don't know why. But it seems that forcing WSL to use *spawn* as the start method fixes the issue. Note that I have changed the call to `apply` to `apply_async` so that 12 processes will run in parallel (if you have 12 or more CPU cores). This necessitates doing the incrementing under a lock since this operation is not atomic:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, shared_memory, set_start_method, Lock

def init_pool(the_lock):
    global lock
    lock = the_lock

def counter():
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name = 'shm')
    c = existing_shm.buf
    with lock:
        old_state = c[0]
        new_state = old_state + 1
        c[0] = new_state
    print(new_state)
    existing_shm.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
    set_start_method('spawn')
    lock = Lock()
    p = Pool(12, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock,))
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create = True, size = 1, name= 'shm')
    buffer = shm.buf
    buffer[0] = 0

    for i in range(20):
        #p.apply(counter, args = (state, ))
        p.apply_async(counter)

    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('final value:', buffer[0])

    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
```

Note that for what you are doing in your example, using a `multiprocessing.Value` would be simpler and will work without forcing the *spawn* method:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value

def init_pool(the_value):
    global v
    v = the_value

def counter():
    with v.get_lock():
        old_state = v.value
        new_state = old_state + 1
        v.value = new_state
    print(new_state)


if __name__=='__main__':
    v = Value('i', 0, lock=True)
    p = Pool(12, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(v,))

    for i in range(20):
        p.apply_async(counter)

    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('final value:', v.value)
```

**Update 2**

I have removed the requirement that *spawn* be used for starting new processes. But for some reason the shared memory must be created prior to creating the pool. For platforms that use `fork`, the pool processes could now access handle `shm`, since it will be inherited. But the code does not *seem* to rely on that because it is explicitly obtaining a handle by calling `existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name = 'shm')`. Perhaps somebody can explain this phenomenon.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, shared_memory, Lock

def init_pool(the_lock):
    global lock
    lock = the_lock

def counter():
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name = 'shm')
    c = existing_shm.buf
    with lock:
        old_state = c[0]
        new_state = old_state + 1
        c[0] = new_state
    print(new_state)
    existing_shm.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create = True, size = 1, name= 'shm')
    p = Pool(12, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock,))
    buffer = shm.buf
    buffer[0] = 0

    for i in range(20):
        #p.apply(counter, args = (state, ))
        p.apply_async(counter)

    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('final value:', buffer[0])

    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
```

Here is code that should work on all platforms. Here the shared memory handle is explicitly passed to each pool process as a global:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, shared_memory, Lock

def init_pool(the_lock, the_shared_memory):
    global lock, shm
    lock, shm = the_lock, the_shared_memory

def counter():
    c = shm.buf
    with lock:
        old_state = c[0]
        new_state = old_state + 1
        c[0] = new_state
    print(new_state)


if __name__=='__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create = True, size = 1, name= 'shm')
    buffer = shm.buf
    buffer[0] = 0

    p = Pool(12, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock, shm))

    for i in range(20):
        #p.apply(counter, args = (state, ))
        p.apply_async(counter)

    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('final value:', buffer[0])

    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
```

Comment: I wonder if this is because there exists variables still pointing towards the shared memory block when the processes quit. Would explicitly doing `del c` right before the `existing_shm.close()` help here?

Comment: @Charchit It was a good idea to try, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: See updated solution that uses `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` class.

Comment: And I have a second update.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get is that as it process in the pool exists, as a result of the `Pool.join` call, it finds out that the shared memory object has not been unlinked yet.

The way out of it would be to create another function in your subprocess, and use a combination of inter-process comunication primitives such as Semaphores and Barriers, so that each process would run the target `counter` function,
call `shm.close()`, wait for the main process to call `shm.unlink()`, and only them return, allowing the process to be terminated.
(The order of the `.join` call in the main process would also have to be changed).

All in all, it turns out you will be better of using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` which is a higher level structure to handle the life cycle of worker processes and submitted tasks. (The underlying processes, though opaque from the main Process, can use any of the tools available through the multiprocessing module).

So, once the Executor keeping the child processes alive and take care of their disposal, and handling the execution of parallel tasks properly, your code might be:

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, Lock

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor, as_completed

import time, random

lock = Lock()

def counter():
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name = 'shm')
    c = existing_shm.buf
    with lock:
        old_state = c[0]
        time.sleep(random.random()/10)
        new_state = old_state + 1
        c[0] = new_state
    print(new_state)
    existing_shm.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
    with Executor(12) as p:
        shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create = True, size = 1, name= 'shm')
        buffer = shm.buf
        buffer[0] = 0

        futures = [p.submit(counter) for i in range(20)]
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            pass

        shm.close()
        shm.unlink()
```

Comment: Your locking mechanism will not work under plain Windows since each pool process will have its own distinct `lock` instance. That is, this will not work with the *spawn* start method,

Comment: That's odd, why would the pool processes need to ensure that the memory block is unlinked before returning? That makes `shared_memory` pretty unappealing.

Comment: as is put in the comments above, maybe calling `unlink` before all sub-processes are done will work. What is certain is that  if the sub-process ends before the SharedMemory is unlinked, you will get the current error message.

Comment: And another quite sure thing is that a concurrent.futures.Executor is easier to deal with, and offers fienr control over tasks than using raw multi-processing.

Comment: @Booboo - indeed. It turns out distributing multiprocessing synchronization objects using `concurrent.futures` would be far from trivial (apart from passing them along as arguments for all tasks). Maybe it would be worth crafting a package that could include higher level needed patterns for that?

Comment: @jsbueno I don't believe you can pass a lock explicitly to a pool worker function. See my answer below and you will see how you can/should initialize each process in the pool with a static variable that is the *identical* `multiprocessing.Lock` instance.